# Convert dataframe column with Json Array content into separate columns

Tags: python, json

i have a column dataframe with a json array that i want to split in columns for every row.

**Dataframe**

```
      FIRST_NAME                                       CUSTOMFIELDS
    0       Maria [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU...
    1       John  [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU...
    ...
```

**Goal**

I need convert the json content in that column into a dataframe

```
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| FIRST NAME |   FIELD_NAME    | FIELD_VALUE | CUSTOM_FIELD_ID |
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| Maria      | CONTACT_FIELD_1 | EN          | CONTACT_FIELD_1 |
| John       | CONTACT_FIELD_1 | false       | CONTACT_FIELD_1 |
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet below should work for you.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['FIELD'] = [[{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALUE': 'EN', 'CUSTOM_FIELD_ID': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1'}, {'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_10', 'FIELD_VALUE': 'false', 'CUSTOM_FIELD_ID': 'CONTACT_FIELD_10'}]]

temp_dict = {}
counter = 0
for entry in df['FIELD'][0]:
    temp_dict[counter] = entry
    counter += 1

new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, orient='index')

new_dataframe #outputs dataframe
```

**Edited answer to reflect edited question:**

Under the assumption that each entry in CUSTOMFIELDS is a list with 1 element (which is different from original question; the entry had 2 elements), the following will work for you and create a dataframe in the requested format.

```
import pandas as pd

# Need to recreate example problem
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['CUSTOMFIELDS'] = [[{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALUE': 'EN', 'CUSTOM_FIELD_ID': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1'}], 
                      [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALUE': 'FR', 'CUSTOM_FIELD_ID': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1'}]]
df['FIRST_NAME'] = ['Maria', 'John']

#begin solution
counter = 0
dataframe_solution = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dataframe_solution = pd.concat([dataframe_solution, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row['CUSTOMFIELDS'][0], orient = 'index').transpose()], sort = False, ignore_index = True)
    dataframe_solution.loc[counter,'FIRST_NAME'] = row['FIRST_NAME']
    counter += 1
```

Your dataframe is in `dataframe_solution`

Comment: Thank you jammin, i forgot to mention get the json array field values for every json document. i've completed my question

Comment: Originally, you had a list in the CUSTOMFIELDS column with 2 elements in it. Is that still the case?

Comment: Made an assumption about the data but let me know if that doesn't work and I need to adjust it

Comment: @Vince no problem! Happy to help!